# Unable to print object passed via Handlebars template

Tags: handlebars.js

I have the following in **main.js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var source = $('#fetch-results').html();
    var dataTemplate = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var $results = $('#results');

    $('.fetch-btn').on('click', function (e) {

        let parameters = { site_url: 'http://feeds.feedburner.com/Techcrunch'};

        $.get('/update', parameters, function(data){
            if (data instanceof Array) {                
                $results.html(dataTemplate({articles: data}));
            } else {
                $results.html(data);
            }           
        });
    })
});
```

and the following in **index.hbs**:

```
<head>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.min.js"></script>  
</head>

.
.
.

            <div id="results">

                <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="fetch-results">
                 <ul>
                        {{#each articles}}
                            <div class="row">{{title}}</div>
                        {{/each}}
                </ul>
                </script>
            </div>
```

I've been trying for hours now to print the contents of the 'articles' object which has the following structure:

```
[
           {
                "title": "Instagram is testing screenshot alerts for stories",
                "author": "Fitz Tepper"
            },
            {
                "title": "A group of industry insiders are putting Russian election meddling up for ad awards",
                "author": "Jonathan Shieber"

            },
            {
                "title": "The Trump administration is reportedly moving to privatize the International Space Station",
                "author": "Jonathan Shieber"
            }
]
```

I've tried all possible ways to get it to print something - {{#with articles}}, {{#articles}}, etc - but it won't just do anything.  I have confirmed through console.log statements in the main.js that the 'data' object - which is being assigned to 'articles before handing it over to the .hbs -  has all the information.

Interestingly, doing this:

```
         <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="fetch-results">
                <ul>
                    {{#each this}}
                        <div class="row">{{@key}}</div>
                    {{/each}}
                </ul>
            </script>
```

displays the following:

```
settings
pageTitle
pageHeading
path
contents
_locals
cache
```

which I can only guess is coming from a different 'this' context, probably in the browser.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try with this line - `$('#results').html(template(contents));` ?

Comment: I do not have any variable with the name 'contents' in my code. Can you please elaborate? thanks.

Comment: `contents` = `dataTemplate`

Comment: I had to install browserify to be able to use the 'template' method as suggested by you. Browserify is however throwing an error: "Uncaught exception:  Unknown template object: function"....This is what I did:   

const hs = require('../../node_modules/handlebars');
const template = hs.template();

and then:  

 $results.html(template(dataTemplate));

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is with the line `$results.html(dataTemplate({ articles: data }));` as the code is working fine when the array is hardcoded.

Please have a look at this example [PEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/wyrEjp)

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, I think there's something going on with the 'dataTemplate(object)' part in that line. But I am not sure about the second part of your statement, asI I tried hard-coding the array in the JQuery click function to make sure that it is not the data returned from the server that is causing the issue.  The hard-coded array also would not print in the HTML.  I've abandoned Handlebars for now and using simple DOM manipulation with JQuery but will revisit this issue again in the future. Thanks.